# Test to check if Cmdlet is Supported

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that keeps throwing this error

```
Get-ComputerRestorePoint : This functionality is not supported on this operating system.
At line:1 char:25
+ Get-ComputerRestorePoint <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-ComputerRestorePoint], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetComputerRestorePointNotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetComputerRestorePoin
   tCommand
```

Is there a simple way to test to see if a cmdlet is supported before running it? I know I can throw a try catch around the cmdlet, but it this approach seems rather expensive compare to a simple check.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily check if a cmdlet is available in your session (using Get-Command) but there is not a direct way to test if an available cmdlet supports the current OS.  The help notes section for this cmdlet says:

```
NOTES

        To run a Get-ComputerRestorePoint command on Windows Vista and later versions 
        of Windows, open Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option.

        This cmdlet uses the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) SystemRestore 
        class.
```

However I wouldn't rely on the Notes being accurate.  The best I can think of is what you suggest, use try/catch.